# Debugging in Debug or Release mode flag vs running without debugging

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm debugging my C# project (WCF) in both Debug and Release modes all the time. When I'm debugging I want the unhandled exception to show where it was thrown. When I'm not debugging the application in Debug or Release modes, I'm catching all the unhandled exceptions and logging them. Right now I do this by adding and removing codes. When not debugging, I add the exception handle code and remove it when I'm debugging.

Is there a code or flag that shows that the currently running application is being debugged in Visual Studio whether in Debug or Release modes. This is different from simple Debug and Release settings. Basically any flag or code that says this application is currently linked up with VS debugging mechanism (regardless of Release or Debug modes). I could be running the application without debugging even in in Debug mode and this flag will tell me that it is not linked up with Visual Studio for debugging purposes.

Comment: The normal way to do this is `#if DEBUG throw; #endif` and only use debug mode (not release). I dont think theres an easy way to do what youre asking if your production code is built off the release build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "flag" in code for checking for DEBUG/RELEASE builds, but you can create one your self with preprocessor checking

```
#if DEBUG
    const bool isDebugCompile = true;
#else
    const bool isDebugCompile = false;
#endif
```

To check if running from Visual Studio (or another debugger) there is a built in API to check for that.

```
bool runningWithDebugger = System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached;
```

A completely different approach would be to use the [`Trace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.aspx) class and configure different trace listeners depending on your debugging scenario, this way you could easy reconfigure your logging behavior from a single point (either in code or configuration).
Yet another alternative in the same line of thought is to use a logging library, like log4net or the Logging Application Block in Enterprise Library and configure the logging behavior from there.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    // ...
}
```

Btw, I believe this has been asked before.